# Vba population rows with formula

Tags: excel, formulas, vba

I have a sheet with 100 columns in each row. 
The column in row one has to be populated with data

Such as

```
B2= Indirect("'sheet1'!N105")
C2= Indirect("'sheet1'!S105")
```

And so how it goes till column CW100.

The data to be fetched from sheet 1 is present at interval of 5 column like 
N105, S105, X105 and so on.

Is there a simpler way to do it at once,instead of manually entering the formulas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `B2` you can use something like

```
=INDIRECT("'sheet1'!R105C"&5*COLUMN()+4,FALSE)
```

The **R1C1** form of `INDIRECT` is invoked by using `FALSE` as the second parameter and the source column number is calculated as 5X the destination column number plus an offset of 4.

You might also be able to use `OFFSET` instead `INDIRECT`, with similar calculation of source columns.

Hope that helps